# Retrieve data from MockRepository?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm new to Unit Testing and I'm using Rhino Mock in ASP.NET MVC

I have created a main test class with this code :

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class PersistenceTest
    {
        [Test]
        protected T SaveAndLoadEntity<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
        {
            var mockDataSource = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<T>>();

            mockDataSource.Add(entity);

            var fromDb = mockDataSource.FindBy(entity.Id);

            return fromDb;
        }
    }
```

and create a customer test class like this :

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class CustomerTests : PersistenceTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Can_Save_And_Load_Customer()
        {
            var customer = new Customer()
            {
                Id = 12,
                Name = "Reza",
                Family = "Pazooki",
                Company = "Rozaneh",
                Email = "ipazooki@gmail.com",
                Mobile = "09352463668",
                Fax = "021-44869059",
                Tel = "021-44869059",
                WebSite = "www.rozanehmedia.com"
            };

            var fromDb = SaveAndLoadEntity(customer);

            fromDb.ShouldNotBeNull();
        }
    }
```

but when run the code, it says that return value from Database is NULL!!!

I don't know what is wrong with my code but I save and retrieve data from mock repository and it seems every thing is ok.

tnx form any help in forward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Mocks**](http://www.mockobjects.com/) are used to record invocations on objects for further verification or to provide values when called (later behavior requires setup).

In your `SaveAndLoadEntity` method you make calls to mock (`Add` and `FindBy`). Since mock is a fake object with no real behavior, **those calls do nothing** (they don't save nor extract any entities to/from database).

If you want to test persistence layer you should be doing tests against *real* database instance (or optionally, *in-memory* one).

```
// [Test] attribute is not needed
protected T SaveAndLoadEntity<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
{
    var dataSource = new DataSource("connection string");
    dataSource.Add(entity);
    var fromDb = dataSource.FindBy(entity.Id);
    return fromDb;
}
```

At the moment you are making calls to **not-setup mock** which doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jimmy_keen.

I change my code according to your advice like this and it worked great :)

```
[TestFixture]
public class PersistenceTest
{
    protected ISession Session;

    protected ITransaction Transaction;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var helper = new NHibernateHelper("...connectionString....");

        Session = helper.SessionFactory.OpenSession();

        Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
    }
    protected T SaveAndLoadEntity<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        Session.Save(entity);

        Transaction.Commit();

        var fromDb = Session.Get<T>(entity.Id);

        return fromDb;
    }
}
```